# Как сделать правильную архитектуру БД при множественных связях в pivot-таблице?

Tags: php, laravel, relation

В базе данных есть следующие таблицы:

- users (id, name, surname)
- teams (id, name)
- roles (id, name)
- permissions (id, name)
- team_role_permission (team_id, role_id, permission_id)
- team_user (user_id, team_id, role_id)

Не понимаю, как именно я должен описать отношения в таблице `team_role_permission` и `team_user`. В обычных отношениях laravel нет возможности создать many-to-many отношение с 3 полями. Если говорить про практику, то мне нужно иметь лишь 3 описанных отношения в БД:

- В каких командах играет игрок и какова его роль в каждой из них (метод `teams` в модели `User/Player`)
- Какие игроки состоят в команде и каковы их роли (метод `players` в модели `Team`)

Таблица `team_role_permission` нужна, поскольку в каждой команде создатель может кастомно выбирать роли для каждой роли пользователей.

Answer (score 5):

По идее это может выглядеть вот так. И никто не запрещает вам создать модель TeamUser, в которой вы укажете нужные связи. Ну или как вы делали, но опять же с созданием промежуточной таблицы со связями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Начнем по порядку:

> "В каких командах (team_id) играет игрок (user_id) и какова его
>   роль(role_id) в каждой из них (метод teams в модели User/Player)"

Для этого существует team_user (user_id, team_id, role_id). Понятней было бы в таком порядке team_id, user_id, role_id.

> "Какие игроки (user_id) состоят в команде (team_id) и каковы их роли
>   (role_id) (метод players в модели Team)"

Данный вопрос покрывает та же связь team_user (user_id, team_id, role_id).

> "Таблица team_role_permission нужна, поскольку в каждой команде
>   (team_id) создатель (?) может кастомно выбирать роли (role_id) для
>   каждой роли(role_id) пользователей (user_id)."

Возможно имелось ввиду "выбирать роли (role_id) для каждого пользователя (user_id)", тогда team_role_permission не нужна. Точнее нужна только для связи команды с permission.
Но, если все таки имелось ввиду то, что написано, тогда должна существовать связь "создатель", team_id, user_id, role_id, role_id. По сути это подмена роли другой ролью, что в общем не очень хорошо.

Если у одного игрока может быть несколько ролей в одной команде тогда связь team_user следовало бы разбить на две:  team_user (team_id, user_id) и team_user__role(team_user_id, role_id).